# How to disable Django Generics Filters Case-Sensitivity

Tags: django, generics, case-sensitive, django-generic-views

I'm using Django Generics to get and filter my data. But it's Case-Sensitive and I wounder if there's a way to disable it?

for example if I send this request, I don't get any results, because the mail address in the database is Test.test@test.com

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/?email=test.test@test.com
```

I tried to use __iexact, but it didn't work!

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ("__all__")
```

View:

```
class all_users(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = eden_serializers.UserSerializer
    filterset_fields = ('__all__')
    permission_classes = [DjangoModelPermissionsWithRead, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.User.objects
```

Url:

```
path('api/users/', views.all_users.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0):

For case insensitive you should consider using `icontains` Field lookups.
[icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-icontains) is used for Case-insensitive containment test. Taking example from official documentation.

Example:

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__icontains='Lennon')
```

SQL equivalent:

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline ILIKE '%Lennon%'
```

Comment: Thanks... But how can I use it with generics.ListAPIView for every fields?